# How to bind daemon to inbound/outbound listening port on ubuntu

Tags: monerod, light-wallet, spv, ports

I would like to connect simplewallet or the GUI to a remote daemon

In my remote compute instance, how would I bind the daemon to the right ports?

`Net service bound to 0.0.0.0:18080`

`Core RPC server initialized OK on port: 18081`

There is the core port and the rpc server port, but they are only accessible on localhost

Also, can you detail any other considerations with regard to privacy that this introduces?

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you have to open the port to outside connections. A tutorial that covers this is on the getmonero.org webpage: https://getmonero.org/knowledge-base/user-guides/vps_run_node

If you are running this from your home, you will likely have to configure your router as well to allow such connections. This will vary by router, but usually just involves forwarding a port to your node.

Finally, make sure you launch bitmonerod with the `--restricted-rpc` parameter to make sure folks don't mine on your node or anything.